# How to expire session in java?

Tags: java, session, servlets

I want to expire a session of user if he successed to login and try to cause harm to my web site, If i detect the attack, I redirect him to Error Page, and want to expire his session.How can I make it?

Comment: Realistically, what would expiring the session actually achieve that you're not already doing?

Comment: @Anon- is it not effective way to log out attacker?

Comment: Abandon(); is not a method in Session Interface!

Comment: @Alaa: What does logging out an attacker actually achieve?

Comment: This is the first thing I will do, log him out, then I can do more mechanims such as stop his accout.

Comment: I got an idea, i can expire his session by make time out is the current time, then I should make an filter to check when session time out, it returns him to the Login page.what do u think about this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the session has an invalidate method.

```
session.invalidate();
```

Look at the API

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html

you probably want to do more than just log out the user; maybe disable the account, log the incident, etc...

For getting the user to the error page, you can use either forward or redirect.  If it makes sense, you should use

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Stop doing bad things");
```

check out

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/api/index.html

Comment: I didn't find an exlecit method doing what L need.

Comment: @alaa where are you having trouble?  Can you get the session in your servlet?

Comment: yes, I can have it, but i want to expire it then forword request to error page, so user cannot return back to the page.

Comment: @Alaa -- The content you send to the client is entirely up to you once you invalidate the session. Look at `request.getRequestDispatcher().foward()` and `response.sendError()`

Comment: The content is up to me, that's ok,BUT how can i prevent him to go back to the page he was already in.

Comment: Don't forget that if you are using jsp to create the error page it will recreate the session by default unless you tell it not to. Use <%@ page session="false" %> to stop the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can invalidate his session, but that's not enough.  If that's all you do, he can immediately login again to create a new session.  Or zap his session cookie and start again.

You've also got to either disable or remove his account entirely, or remove the access rights that allow him to do whatever it is you are trying to prevent.  (And in the extreme case, you may also need to start blocking access based on IP addresses, etc.)

> BUT how can i prevent him to go back to the page he was already in.

You cannot prevent him using "back", or reentering the URL from his browser history, or by typing it into the navigation bar.

What you need to do is stop him *fetching* the page from the server.  If he is not logged in, or he doesn't have the relevant access rights, then your server should respond with the "Unauthorized" or "Permission denied" status code whenever he tries to view the page ... or perform other request that should not be allowed.

Don't just rely on stopping him seeing the page.  You also need to implement server-side access controls on the requests that can be made from the page.